# Limit characters in post_meta (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I limit the characters in this code?

```
.get_post_meta($post->ID,'smple1',true).
```

I have tried with the following:

```
$trim_length = 21;  //desired length of text to display 
$custom_field = 'smple1';  
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);    
if ($value) {    
  echo '.rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length)) . ';  
}
```

But I get server error. I must be missing an endif or something?

Many thanks.

Comment: If your first line is an exact representation of your code, you're using apostrophes around 'smple1' instead of quotation marks like "smple1", which will return an error because of the outer most apostrophes.

Comment: actually, the first line of code (original) is working (both with "" or '')the 2nd code, when i change to $custom_field="smple1" then code seems right, and i can see my page, however i see the code it self

Comment: i found an answer to my question at other page on this site, which they recommend using `$text = strip_tags(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smple1', true));
echo substr($text, 0, 100) . "...";` however its not working nither in my case, i tried as you recommended to put somple in ""

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the meta value, make sure that it was in `false` and then use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the 21 characters, or fewer if the field is shorter based on the results of [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

```
$length = 21;
$custom_field = 'smple1';

$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $custom_field, true );
if ( false !== $value ){
    echo substr( $value, 0, (strlen($value) < $length)? strlen($value) : $length );
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code as well as `$text = strip_tags(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smple1', true)); echo substr($text, 0, 100) . "...";` as someone else recommended, but this code is being printed on pagge

Comment: You have to surround it in `<?php ?>` tags... might be good to check out http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Answer (score 0):

> Display no of character using your custom meta key's value:

```
<?php
      $trim_length = 21;
      $custom_field = 'lp_sub_description';  
      $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);    
      if ($value) {    
        $data = rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length));
        echo $data;  
       } 
?>
```

**Also use simple code :**

```
<?php echo substr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lp_sub_description', true), 0, 21); ?>
```

Comment: what if the meta value is `false` or less than 21 characters?

Comment: lp_sub_description is a metakey.
less then 21 character not effect on a text as it is display text.

Answer (score -1):

Ok after many tests it worked in my case as following:

```
$filetext = (get_post_meta($post->ID, "smple1", true));
'.substr($filetext, 0, 8) . "...".'
```

note when to put `'. and .'`

Comment: That is invalid PHP and will fail if the meta value is `false` or less than 8 characters.